# Retornar a última posição de um elemento em uma cadeia de caracteres

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Desejo que o código retorne a ultima posição de uma letra, no caso a letra `'a'`, que aparece em uma frase.

```
frase = input('Escreva uma frase: ').lower()
print(frase.find('a', -1, -len(frase)))
```

O código está retornando `-1`, ou seja, que não foi encontrada nenhuma letra `'a'`.

Onde está o erro?

Comment: Considero que é um erro de digitação, pois está utilizando o valor `-len(frase)`. Quando na verdade deveria utilizar `len(frase)` (sem o sinal de `menos`).

Comment: como eu quero que venha de traz para frente começo do -1 e vou ate o - tamanho da str.

Comment: O segundo e terceiro argumentos do `find` indicam apenas o intervalo no qual será feito a busca. Por exemplo, `find('a', 4, 7)` restringe a busca entre as posições 4 e 7 da string (em vez de procurar na string inteira), mas isso não quer dizer que ela será feita de trás pra frente. Na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/559562/112052) abaixo eu explico um pouco melhor porque não funciona

Comment: eu tinha votado para fechar, mas pode ser aproveitado realmente. vlw @hkotsubo.

Comment: Respostas baseadas em pilhas ou expressões regulares serão bem vindas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind), basta usar o método `rfind`:

```py
frase = input('Escreva uma frase: ').lower()
print(frase.rfind('a'))
```

Funciona de forma similar à `find`, mas em vez de retornar o índice da primeira ocorrência, retorna o índice da última (ou `-1` se não for encontrado).

---

No seu caso, retornou `-1` porque os índices que você indicou para a busca não fazem sentido. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), ao fazer `string.find(sub, start, end)`, a busca é feita no intervalo `string[start:end]`.

Por exemplo, se o tamanho da string for 3, ao passar `-1` e `-len(frase)`, a busca está sendo feita no *slice* `[-1:-3]`. Como índices negativos são contados a partir do final da string, então `-1` indica que vai começar pelo último caractere da string, e `-3` indica que vai terminar no antepenúltimo elemento. Portanto, isso é um intervalo vazio, e o resultado é uma string vazia.

Por isso nunca vai achar nada. E mesmo que você passe um intervalo válido, ainda sim a busca **não** será feita "de trás pra frente", então `find` definitivamente não é a solução.

---

Outra forma é usar `rindex` (por exemplo, `frase.rindex('a')`). A diferença é que se não for encontrado nada, ele lança um `ValueError` (e aí precisa de um bloco `try`/`except` para verificar se não foi encontrado):

```py
try:
    print(frase.rindex('a'))
except ValueError:
    print('Não foi encontrado')
```